# Setting an event's target action correctly

Tags: javascript, objective-c

I was wondering how can I set an event's target action correctly? Inside an event handler function in javascript, I have

```
    alert(e.target.getAttribute('action')); // Outputs correctly
    alert(newAction); // Outputs newAction correctly
    e.target.setAttribute('action',newAction); // Seems to be the problem
    alert(e.target.action); // INCORRECT: Has some url prefixed to newAction
```

The new action alert shows some url+newAction, but I just want newAction. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should forget `setAttribute` for standard properties and just use direct property access. So if it's a form, use `e.target.action` for getting and setting the value (less to type too).

Comment: They seem to both do the same thing when I tried both. Would you mind explaining what's the advantage of it besides being shorter?

Comment: Direct access through property assignment for standard properties is simpler and works in all browsers. Using `get/setAttribute` has bugs in some browsers and also works differently depending on browser and version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `alert(e.target.getAttribute('action'))`

Comment: That is extremely weird, I tried that and got the same output as alert(e.target.action). Now it works fine.

Comment: Also as another quick question, I need to pass in input through the URL, do you have any suggestions as to the delimiter? ie. input1;input2;input3.

Comment: The problem is I'll be passing input fields which could technically contain ampersands though. Are there any others?